# redirect to another view with multiple parameter, located in different controller jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, actionresult

I am working on mvc and I am stuck at one place where I want to redirect from a view to another,

I have 2 method in my controller where I want to redirect from one to another,

here is my methods,

```
    public ActionResult Test1()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Rest2()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and my ajax call

```
var url = window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);//to get current url
$.ajax({
    url:  "@Url.Action("../RegForm/Rest2")",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,
    error: function (error) {
    },
    success: function (response) {

    }
});
```

Debugger is going to my controller but returning on same view

what can I do here?

Comment: Are you looking to redirect from one controller to another action?

return RedirectToAction("Home", "Details", new { area = "" });

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect, you absolutely do not need AJAX. You use AJAX only when you want to stay on the same page and update only a portion of it.

So if you only wanted to redirect the browser:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Test2", "Home",new { ID=1, Name="LMK", Date="05-10-18" })'; 
window.location.href = url
```

Comment: and what if the URL contains some variable?

like the url contains 3 variable?

Comment: Test2 contains ID Name, Date,